# Unable to edit configmap in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, edit, kubectl, configmap

I have a already running kubernetes application(eclipse che)
I am editing a configmap with the following command
`kubectl edit cm/che -n che`
When I edit and save it, I get a message saying that the configmap is saved.
But when I again issue the same command I cannot find my changes.
Am I missing some basic step?

Comment: How did you deploy che? did you try deleting cm and recreating it? Also make sure that k8s client and server versions match

Comment: I used chectl to deploy che. Also I checked that client & server versions match

$kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:41:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:32:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you deployed devfile registry with **helm** and you only need only your devfile registry and not the one provided by che try the following -

1. Remove the helm chart by `helm delete che-devfile-registry -n che`
2. `kubectl edit checluster eclipse-che -n che`
3. Add `devfileRegistryImage: 'Your devfile Image'` under
   spec:
   server:
4. Save

After that go to the default che url you should be able to see your custom stack in the list.

Answer (score 0):

use kubectl verbose mode for tracing the problem

```
kubectl edit cm/che -n che -v9
```

I guess it could be related to permissions, admission controls, or operator frameworks.

Comment: Old value of DEVFILE_REGISTRY was https://devfile-registry-che.192.168.99.107.nip.io

Using the -v9 option while editing I can see      

Request Body: {"data":{"CHE_WORKSPACE_DEVFILE__REGISTRY__URL":"https://che-devfile-registry-che.192.168.99.107.nip.io"}}
Response Body: {......"CHE_WORKSPACE_DEVFILE__REGISTRY__URL":"https://che-devfile-registry-che.192.168.99.107.nip.io".......}        


The response contains the updated value of DEVFILE REGISTRY
But when i again do kubectl edit cm/che -n che, i still see the old value of DEVFILE REGISTRY in the cm/che

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Che with operator (through chectl or not), you should change the settings editing the CheCluster custom resource:

```
kubectl edit CheCluster/eclipse-che -n che
```